# fetch body not showing up in the request payload in Hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I've got a Nodejs API server running Hapi.  To test I've got a simple HTML page with some Javascript that is using fetch to hit the API for some data.  The Javascript on that page looks like this:

```
 fetch("http://localhost:3000/lov", {
        method: "POST", 
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: {P_LOV_NAME: "RTSBLANK"}
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(displayData);

function displayData(data) {
    let elem = document.getElementById("screen");
    elem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    console.log(data);
}
```

The problem is that the Hapi endpoint doesn't seem to have the body of the request above.  The code looks like this:

"use strict";

```
exports.plugin = {
    name: "LOV",
    version: "1.0.0",
    register: async function (server, options) {
        server.route({
            config: {
                cors: {
                    origin: ['*'],
                    additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
                }
            },
            method: "POST",
            path: "/lov",
            handler: function(request, h) {
                return getLOV(request, h, server);
            }
        });
    }
};

function getLOV(request, h, server) {
    console.log("Get LOV Request: ", request.payload);
    let res = server.methods.response();
    res.error = false;
    res.msg = "Retrieved LOV.";

    if (request.payload && request.payload.P_LOV_NAME == "RTSBLANK") {
        res.data = server.methods.fake().lovTestUser;
    } else {
        res.data = server.methods.fake().lovBlank;
    }

    return res;
}
```

In the getLOV() function, the request.payload is always null.  I've looked at the request object and it doesn't seem to have the body object anywhere on it.  I'm sort of at a loss here as this doesn't seem like that complex a bit of code.  Am I missing something obvious and stupid?

Comment: Are you trying to use `async-await` here because I can `async` but not `await`.

Comment: I am running exactly the code here.  I'm not using any async functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, indeed, something stupid that I overlooked and then overthought.  The body on the request can't be a JSON object.  You have to use JSON.stringify() on it first.